# What is the best propulsion for an interstellar ship?

Tags: spacecraft, propulsion, interstellar-travel

What is the best propulsion for an interstellar ship? with the current technology
If we sent a spacecraft in this decade or the next, what would be the best propulsion for that ship? I speak of a ship with twice as much as the space station, with technology from now on in 20 years

Comment: Not a duplicate, yet very similar objections to the question: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24455/what-will-be-the-best-way-to-convert-nuclear-fusion-energy-into-thrust-for-a-roc?noredirect=1#comment70324_24455

Comment: We are not within 20 years of making an interstellar spacecraft. No interstellar-capable propulsion technology is far enough along to evaluate it as "best".

Comment: @RussellBorogove  its for  a tale

Comment: Give Project Rho a look, there’s enough detail there for fiction, and plenty of choices. http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/

Comment: No way we could develop an interstellar manned spaceship within 20 years. ion engine driven by a nuclear reactor is the best/faster to complete bet for propulsion I think.

Comment: Project Icarus has a timeframe of around 80 years
http://www.icarusinterstellar.org/

Comment: You might want to try asking on [Worldbuilding.stackexchange.com](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to read their help and check to see if someone has already asked this first.