# Where can I find list of deep space probes launched but yet to land on celestial bodies etc?

Tags: history, deep-space, reference-request, space-program

How can I find list of all deep space probes that have launched, but not yet landed on any celestial bodies?

Comment: I've made a small edit to your question. "deep space" in this site usually means beyond the Earth-Moon system, and I think that's what you mean. If you want to include the Moon, change "deep space" to "beyond Earth". One question though, do you mean probes that are planned to land but haven't landed yet? There have been many launched that never had a plan to land anywhere. New Horizons is a recent example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resource that's regularly updated is the Wikipedia [List of active Solar System probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_active_Solar_System_probes)

This also includes probes not intended to land, and probes that have already landed, but since the list only has 25 entries a time of writing, filtering is not a huge job (relevant keywords being "arrival" and "lander").

As of November 2020, the only landers en route are the [Perseverance Mars rover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseverance_(rover)) and the [Tianwen-1 mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianwen-1)

Comment: Depending on your definition you could add OSIRIS-REX and Hayabusa 2 to that list since they are in flight and will land (on earth) soon. And most orbiter missions plan to crash in their respective planets in the end.

Comment: @uhoh "a factor of 2" was most unhelpful. Untangling the puzzle, the mission missing from the wikipedia page appears to be Tianwen-1, and I have updated the article accordingly.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys specific information about factor of ~1000 errors given [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48154/which-theoretical-propulsion-system-has-the-highest-specific-impulse/48156#comment155575_48156) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48365/collect-helium-3-in-the-space-not-surfaces?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment156288_48366) has so far been ignored. Wikipedia is known to be an unreliable source, so "go look it up in Wikipedia" is not a good answer. But I don't know if there is a better one.